# IntelliJ multi line editing shortcuts on Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, intellij-idea, resharper

I am very used to the IntelliJ and have found the multi-line cursor hotkeys extremely helpful while coding.

Particularly, the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> command "add selection for next occurrence" and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> "deselect occurrence" have made my programming speed increase exponentially.

I've always been able to find a simple plugin for sublime, atom, etc. for the Idea key mapping, however for this scenario nothing seems to be working. I've installed the trial version of Resharper by Jetbrains as well as:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys2017-KeyboardShortcuts

Maybe it's not possible to implement these various intellij editing features or it's an installation issue regarding Resharper or the link above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Multi Edit Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode) and [MixEdit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcoAlamia-CodingLabs.MixEdit) extensions.